# module 'gspread.worksheet' has no attribute 'update_cell'

Tags: python, gspread

My code:

```
import gspread
from gspread import worksheet
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("keys.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
spreadsheet = client.open("ackerwaldundwiese")
worksheet.update_cell(1, 2, "car")
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mm\PycharmProjects\pythonProject1\ddf.py", line 8, in <module>
    worksheet.update_cell(1, 2, "car")
AttributeError: module 'gspread.worksheet' has no attribute 'update_cell'
```

I'm using PyCharm 2022.1.1 (Community Edition) windows 10

Comment: In your showing script, `worksheet` is not defined. But, if `worksheet` is not declared, such an error doesn't occur. By this, I cannot understand your current situation. In order to correctly understand your current issue, can you provide the correct script for correctly replicating your current issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi before accessing a worksheet you must retrieve it first.

In you situation it should be sometlike this:

```py
spreadsheet = client.open("ackerwaldundwiese")
worksheet = spreadsheet.sheet1
worksheet.update_cell(1, 2, "car")
```

Note: this will return the first sheet, if you need to get a different sheet use the method [get_worksheet](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.3.2/api.html#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.get_worksheet)

You should remove this line from your code:

```py
from gspread import worksheet
```

You don't need to import the `Worksheet` object and it is case sensitive so the **w**orksheet object does not exists but the **W**orksheet does.